# Java array get modified

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the problem, let me describe the code.

```
Sort.java
public class Sorting {
public int[] _input;
public  int[] _unsortedInput;
...
public int[] get_unsortedInput() {
     return _unsortedInput;
}
public void set_unsortedInput(int[] _unsortedInput) {
     this._unsortedInput = _unsortedInput;
}
public int[] get_input() {
     return _input;
}
public void set_input(int[] _input) {
     this._input = _input;
}

public void GenerateInput(){
    _input = new int[10];
    _unsortedInput = new int[10];
     for (int i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
         Random rd = new Random();
         _input[i] = rd.nextInt(get_range());
         _unsortedInput[i] = _input[i];
    }
}
public void Sort() {    
}
```

---

```
SelectionSort.java
public class SelectionSort extends Sorting {
public SelectionSort(int[] number) {
     set_input(number);
}    
public void Sort() {    
    int[] number = get_input();
    // sorting logic which update number array only, not _unsortedInput 
    // array
}
```

---

Test.java

```
Sorting s = new Sorting();
s.GenerateInput();
SelectionSort ss = new SelectionSort(s.get_unsortedInput());
s.sort();
```

---

now my question is , after sorting, the _input array get sorted. which is expected. But _unsortedInput array is also get sorted. though I did nothing with this array. Why? How to protect this?

Comment: the mad style of naming class fields

Comment: why is it? @Andrew Tobilko,

Comment: So called variables in C ++, if I'm not mistaken. look at [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: San - What Andrew is saying is that the Java compiler is **punishing** you for egregious violations of the accepted conventions for Java style.  He is joking.

Comment: You also don't need to create a Random object in each loop iteration. It is overkill! Created once, as a class field.

Comment: @user244255 You meant, as an "instance field", or just "field". "class field" can be misinterpreted as a "static field".

Comment: how do I create it once which Random int the class field?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to make it a static final field tbh. In this particular case, at least.

Comment: @San If you only ever call `GenerateInput()` (please lowercase first letter), then just move the `Random rd = new Random();` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @user244255 `Random` should not be used by multiple threads. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Also, `static` in general is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Yes @Andreas, I did it, but after sorting, why _unsortedInput array get changed??

Comment: I know ThreadLocalRandom is the preferred way of sharing a random object between multiple threads nowadays. But there Random has been used and shared between multiple threads. This *can* lead to contention and consequent poor performance, but it is not forbidden, only discouraged nowadays. If his code is gonna be called by a 1000s threads not sharing makes more sense. I took some time to dig where exactly this contention on Random would come from and basically comes from gaussian distribution generator. So, it is discouraged? Yes. Cannot use? No, you can, it is thread safe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my reading of your code, these two lines select the **unsorted** array, and then do an in-place sort.

```
SelectionSort s = new SelectionSort(s.get_unsortedInput());
s.sort();
```

The sequence is this:

1. `Sorting.generateInput()` generates two distinct arrays A1 & A2 with the same values: `_input` refers to A1, and `_unsortedInput` refers to A2.
2. `s.get_unsortedInput()` gets the reference in `_unsortedInput`; i.e A2.
3. The `SelectionSort` constructor does this:

   ```
      public SelectionSort(int[] number) {
          set_input(number);
      }
   ```

   So your constructor call does this:

   1. The parameter `number` will be the reference to A2
   2. The `set_input` call sets `_input` to A2.

      Now we have `_input` and _unsortedInput` both referring to A2.
4. The `s.sort()` call sorts the array that `_input` refers to, which is also the array that `_unsortedInput` refers to.
5. You (incorrectly) observe that you have sorted "both" arrays.  The reality is that `_input` and `_unsortedInput` are now that same array (A2) ... because of what the `set_input` call did.

---

> Why?

See above.

And actually, there is another bug, 'cos you actually wrote:

```
SelectionSort ss = new SelectionSort(s.get_unsortedInput());
s.sort();
```

You are calling `sort` on `s` instead of `ss`.  And things get even more confused.

> How to protect this?

Ermm ... it is a bug in your code.  How do you project against writing code with bugs in it?  In general, there is no solution ...

However, if your `Sorting` class needs to record two arrays, and allow you to choose which one to sort, then I would use a third variable; e.g.

```
   protected final int[] input;
   protected final int[] unsortedInput;
   protected int[] arrayToBeSorted;
```

Note the `final` ... so that you don't accidentally change those array references!

The replace the two setters with a `setArrayToBeSorted`, and change the `sort` method to sort whatever `arrayToBeSorted` refers to.

There is also a problem with class hierarchy and proper division of responsibility.  The API for your `SelectionSort` copnstructor is basically wrong.  It needs to be changed so that your test code can do this:

```
  SelectionSort ss = new SelectionSort();
  ss.generateInput();
  ss.setArrayToBeSorted(ss.getInput());
  ss.sort();
```

Or better still, get rid of the error-prone selection mechanism.

---

Finally, read the [Java Style Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), especially the sections that talk about identifier conventions.

Comment: I got your point, How to avoid this situation, I want my every  sort get input from _unsortedInput array, and do a sort. ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you call `set_input` in `SelectionSort.`
Replace `set_input` with `set_unsortedInput` in this contructor.

Comment: I don't make you understand it. after sorting _input changed,  and also _unsortedInput chnged. which is not expected

Comment: When you create `SelectionSort ss = new SelectionSort(s.get_unsortedInput());`, you pass unsorted array from `s`. In the constructor you assign it to `_input` of object `ss`.
Notice that after all operations you have `s._input` unsorted, and `s._unsortedInput` is sorted, `ss._input` sorted and `s._unsortedInput` is `null`